# How to update the Modified Date of folders with a batch file?

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file, timestamp, file-properties

`copy /b Source+,,` updates a file's Modified Date.

Is there a method for folders?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a simple way to change the date.
Neither renaming nor changing attributes has an effect on the modified date.

Currently, the only way seems to rename the directory, create a new one and move the content from the old to the new directory.
That's only a nasty solution.