# Windows shell touch folder-date for specific folders

Tags: windows, shell, directory

i want to run a windows script which is supposed to change the datetime of one or more folders to recent datetime. It shall run via task scheduler every night at midnight. I need to fetch all folders which are from that day and not older.

Source:

- M:\Test\Folder.1 2024-03-01 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.2 2024-03-02 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.3 2024-03-03 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.4 2024-03-04 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.5 2024-03-05 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.6 2024-03-06 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.7 2024-03-07 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.8 2024-03-07 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.9 2024-03-07 16:01

Target after script run on 2024-03-07 23:59:

- M:\Test\Folder.1 2024-03-01 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.2 2024-03-02 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.3 2024-03-03 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.4 2024-03-04 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.5 2024-03-05 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.6 2024-03-06 16:01
- M:\Test\Folder.7 2024-03-07 23:59
- M:\Test\Folder.8 2024-03-07 23:59
- M:\Test\Folder.9 2024-03-07 23:59

Any ideas how to do that?
thanks and kind regards
silencer

currently i am not able to fetch the folders from today :D

Comment: More details are needed. "i want to run a windows script" - Batch? Powershell? WSH? Something else? "change the datetime of one or more folders" - Creation date and time? Date and time modified? Last accessed date and time?

Comment: Hi Fiddling, thanks for your reply! I want to change Date and time modified. No matter what kind of script but i prefere batch.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have stated in the comments that batch solution is preferred, I would refer you to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808046/6133426). To quote the original author:

> I can't see a simple way to change the date.
>
> Neither renaming nor changing attributes has an effect on the modified date.
>
> Currently, the only way seems to rename the directory, create a new one and move the content from the old to the new directory.
>
> That's only a nasty solution.

Since that's **is** a nasty solution, and since you mentioned that any script would do, I'm using Powershell.

```
# path to check for directories
$parentDirectory = "M:\Test\"
<# date used is in YYYY-MM-DD format
the date below is for testing purposes, use it instead of the original
to see it in action
# $cutoffDate = "2024-01-01"
#>
$cutoffDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

# test if the path is valid
if(-not (Test-Path -Path $parentDirectory) ) {
    Write-Host Path does not exist
    Exit
}

# loop through all the first-level directories
# keep only those with desired date
Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDirectory -Directory | 
Foreach-Object {
    # get the last modified date
    $directoryModDate = $(Get-Item $_.FullName).lastwritetime
    # convert it to YYYY-MM-DD
    $directoryModDate = Get-Date $directoryModDate -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

    # compare it to our cutoff date
    # if it's older, skip it
    if($directoryModDate -lt $cutoffDate) {
        # skip it. uncomment the following line to see the skipped ones
        # Write-Host Skipping $directoryModDate " --- " $cutoffDate
        return
    }

    # not earlier than the cutoff date, we can work with it
    # uncomment the following line to see the picked up date
    # Write-Host $directoryModDate
    $(Get-Item $_.FullName).lastwritetime = $(Get-Date ($cutoffDate + " 23:59:00"));
}
```

---

See the comments within the code to understand how it works.

### Limitations

The script has a couple of limitations:

- it's not recursive. That means that it will only process first-level directories, and will not check their contents. The reason for that - it wasn't in your original request
- it doesn't perform regex matching for directory names against a pattern. For example, there's no (in pseudocode) `<dir_name> -match "Folder\..*"` in the script. This lack of regex name matching means that any directory within `M:\Test\` which has a `Date modified` equal to today's date will have its `lastwritetime` changed to be `<today> 23:59:00`. The reason for this omission is the same as for the previous one - it wasn't in your original request

Before you use the script for real, I suggest setting up a small test case. Save the code in a *.ps1 file, set up a test directory enviroment, set up a scheduled task to run your *.ps1 script, and see if the `Date modified` of your directories have been changed properly.

Comment: Thanks exactly what i need! Huge thanks to you Fiddling!! Very nice work!